# How to return each element of a list as a new line in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, zsh

I’d like to return the variable `additionalactions` as a paragraph delimited string so that it is easy to split back in zsh. Like so, it is returned as a comma separated string.

```
#!/bin/zsh

WER=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3")    

read -r -d '' SELECTWER << EOF
set actions to the paragraphs of "$(printf '%s\n' "${WER[@]}")"
set additionalactions to choose from list actions with prompt "Additional Actions:" default items {"Multiple Instances"} with multiple selections allowed
return additionalactions
EOF

WER=$(osascript -e "$SELECTWER");
```

`WER` prints `Option 2, Option 3`. (Assuming Option 2 and Option 3 were selected in the dialog)
`WER` should print `Option 2\nOption3`. Then I can read the individual lines into an array.

Comment: What's a *"paragraph delimited string"* please? *"Comma delimited"* means comma characters between words. *"Tab delimited"* means tab characters between words. So, what's a paragraph character?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean a linefeed character: `\n`

Comment: Can you run it through `tr` to transliterate commas into linefeeds? `WER=$(osascript ... | tr ',' '\n')`

Comment: Doesn’t work, because I got spaces within the elements of the list.

Comment: Maybe you can show your `WER` array and the returned value from `osascript`?

Comment: Problem is, it is not an array but a string: `Item 1, Item 2, Item 3` I’d like to turn this string into an array, so that I can continue to work on the individual elements in the bash script.

Comment: Surely it is an array as you use `${WER[@]}` to print it?

Comment: Ah yes, I see, this is confusing. So, I declare the array in bash (before the heredoc, I cut it unfortunately). I need the user to chose an item from the list in the Mac UI. The output of that selection is then stored in a variable (unfortunately) named WER aswell. This time, it is an string, that I’d like to convert to an array.

Comment: Ok, please click `edit` under your question and show 1) the contents of `WER` array before `osascript`, 2) the value returned by `osascript` and 3) the value you actually want. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can see, this works fine if appended after the end of your script `echo "$WER" | tr ',' '\n'`

Comment: It works, but leaves a leading whitespace on each line. I got around it like so: `gsed "s/, /\\n/g"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/zsh

WER=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3")    

osascript - "${(@)WER}" << EOF 
    on run argv
        set acts to choose from list argv with multiple selections allowed
        if acts is false then return ""
        set text item delimiters to linefeed
        return acts as string
    end run
EOF
```

Comment: Works fine here. Are you sure you’re in the right shell (zsh, not bash)?

Comment: I know it was a simple question, but this answer is sublime.  I'd give it +4 if it were possible.

Comment: While this is absolutely beautiful, how do I store the returned string in a variable? (Preferably broken up line by line in an Array)

Comment: The syntax is so cryptic it’d make Perl cry, but it’s not hard to find just by searching for ["zsh array split"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460792/split-zsh-array-from-subshell-by-linebreak/460798): `SEL=(${(f)"$(osascript - "${(@)WER}")"}) << EOF … EOF`